# How do I fix this Wrist Twist Issue

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

Does anyone know how to fix this pose issue when rotating hand over the x axis?

Many Thanks
Liam

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't tell a lot about what's the issue and you're trying to do.

From your last picture it might be that the orientation of your bone is not aligned on the others. Display the axis visibility in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data* > *Viewport Display* > *Axes*. If that's the case, select it in Edit mode and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> + value to rotate, or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> to automatically align.

[image]

Also, maybe you should try this:

- Make sure that your arm has enough topology.

[image]

- For your armature, in the *Properties* panel > *Object Data* > *Viewport Display*, choose *Display As* > *B-Bones* (bendy bones) so that they you can twist them (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> to scale in *Edit* mode).

[image]

- Select your forearm bone and segment it.

[image]
[image]

- Give it a *Copy Rotation* constraint, *Space* > *Pose Space*/*Pose Space*. You can reduce its influence if you want.

[image]

Comment: Hi Moonboots, unfortunately as my character is very only 1.7m tall (as it is for ue4), the b  bones are massive compared to the mesh. Here is a photo of what I'm seeing: https://ibb.co/c2wfrYc

Comment: Ctrl Alt S to scale in Edit mode   ;)

Comment: The issue still posits: https://ibb.co/xJKH8tX. I think the problem is that the entire forearm isn't moving because when you move your wrist in real life you can't... it's only the forearm that rotates.

Comment: maybe check the rotation of your bone in Edit mode (if that's the problem), ctrl R to rotate, and Shift N to automatically align on the axis

Comment: After playing around with the rotation in edit mode it still won't work how it should

Comment: ok so maybe share your file (the whole armature + the forearm mesh only): https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: the website doesn't work very well

Comment: or use https://pasteall.org/blend/